# Sine Graph and Cosine Graph

Tags: trigonometry

Can anybody explain to me how is the sin graph complementary to the cos graph as you only shift the sin graph by 90 degrees to get the same graph as the cos one. But by definition complementary is when you add some angles up to get to 90 degrees, but I only see the sin graph getting shifted.

Another question is that I've been told that the cos graph is complementary to the sin graph. Does this mean that the graphs will be the same every 90 degrees?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the deal:
$$\cos x\equiv\sin(90^\circ-x)$$
The angles on both sides of this identity always add up to $90^\circ$, hence the name "complementary". It has little to do with either graph being "shifted".

From this we say that $\sin$ is complementary to $\cos$ and vice versa.